# How to change content of UILabel inside of a closure

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, closures

I can't change content of UILabel inside of a closure. I googled, yet solution is nowhere to be found.

Here is related piece of my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var city: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var message: UILabel!
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        var urlString = "http://google.com"
        var url = NSURL(string: urlString)


        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in

            self.message.text = "try"
            println("done")
        }

        task.resume()
    }
    ... //rest of the code
```

It should change contents of UILabel message with "try" when I click the button. It prints out "done" in the console, but it does not change content of UILabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it by using `dispatch_async` on main thread. UI updates have to be done in the main thread. `dataTaskWithURL` executes in a background thread.

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in

    if (error == nil)
    {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
       {
          self.label.text = "Updated"
       })
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed it the way you proposed, It worked. After that, I added self.message.text = "try" after dispatch_async method now it works too. When I remove dispatch_async method, it does not work.

Comment: Is this a legitimate way to solve this problem or is this just a workaround? What is the main reason of my problem?

Comment: This is the way to solve the problem. Its not a workaround. You have to execute UI updates on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. I already wrapped the 
`UILabel.text = newTitle` in `DispatchQueue.main.async{}`block, but it didn't work. After checking carefully, I found I accidentally declared the function outside of the view controller where the UILabel was declared. Thought I'd write this in case anyone else runs into the same problem! Don't forget to check your indentations:D